# Replacing timestamps in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, text-editing

I have a log file with time stamps on each line such as

```
2012-06-26 21:31:40 Killshot: Something, Something...
2012-06-26 21:31:40 Killed [player name]
2012-06-26 21:31:40 Executing Death Sequence
2012-06-26 21:31:41 Restarting match
```

I want to replace all the timestamps with blank space in N++. How would I go about having it replace all the different timestamps with that blank space?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this expression:

```
\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}
```

As suggested by @slhck, one can use `\d` to replace `[0-9]`, thus reducing the expression.

[image: Notepad++ Print Screen]

**Having difficulties reading the expression:**

`\d` -> any digit from 0 to 9.
`{4}` -> four chars count.
`\d{4}` will search for four numbers.

Repeating this to mach the desired date format, adding the relevant separators like: `-`, `:` and , we've got an expression for this problem.

Comment: You can just use `\d` for a digit instead of `[0-9]`.

Comment: @slhck Tks, updated!